# How do I render a field on a node twice with two different field formatters?

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to render a field on a node twice with different field formatters?

I have a content type with the a field type "Email". This field needs to give me as output:

- A link to the default email form ("Email contact form")
- The original input in the field ("Default email link")

I have put the field formats in quotes above.

Does anyone have a clue on how to do this, or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do what you are after. See [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) for some documentation on rendering a field.

- You will need to replace "HOOK" with the name of your function name.
- You will need to add the correct settings for the display types (can be added to the display types array to keep the data together).
- The settings data can be found in the module that defines the field formatter. Looking through the field formatter definitions is probably the easiest way to find the correct settings for the display you are trying to achieve.
- You will need to ensure your field is called "field_email" or update the code.

Code:

```
<?php

function HOOK_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

    $display_types = array(
        'email_contact',
        'email_default',
    );

    foreach ($display_types as $type) {
        $vars['content']['field_email_' . $type] = field_view_field(
            'node',
            $vars['node'],
            'field_email',
            array(
                'type' => $type,
                'settings' => array(...),
                'label' => 'above',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can output the field twice, using different formatters in the template

e.g, in node.tpl.php something like:

```
$output = array();
$email = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_email');
$output[] = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_email', $email[0], array(
            'type' => 'email_contact'));
$output[] = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_email', $email[0],array(
            'type' => 'email_default'));
print implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
```

Comment: As a string the fifth param is not a formatter but a view mode.

Comment: Yes, it may need a display array instead.

Comment: Hi thx for trying to help me with this. I would like to try your answer but can't figure out where to put it... Could you please explain it a bit more.

Comment: @JimmyRaets you could put the code in node.tpl.php

Comment: Never put such code in a template file. There are the preprocess functions for that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Yes, a preprocess function would be better, thanks.

Comment: Quick and dirty, but still using field_view_value. Untill I learn the HOOK stuff and Drupal8 templating i'll stick to this dirty coding :) It also helps that it can be teaser-specific this way....

Answer (score 0):

Not in core ways. You can, however, render field twice in tpl.php, but it will not give you two formatters.