# How do I render a field twice with two different field formatters?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

So there was already the same question for D7 ([How do I render a field on a node twice with two different field formatters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73041/how-do-i-render-a-field-on-a-node-twice-with-two-different-field-formatters)) but now i wanted to know how to do this in d8.

Maybe this helps a little bit, but i could not get it working.
[Rendering arbitrary field values without a parent entity in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115117/rendering-arbitrary-field-values-without-a-parent-entity-in-drupal-8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in drupal 7 you could use:

```
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_foo', array('type' => 'some_formatter', 'settings' => array(...), $langcode));
```

to render a field with a specific formatter. The drupal 8 the equivalent is:

```
$output = $node->field_foo->view(array('type' => 'some_formatter', 'settings' => array(...)));
```

source: [Change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2208327)

Now to render the fields I would create a preprocess for a node

```
function HOOK_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_field_formatter1'] = $node->field_foo->view(array('type' => 'some_formatter', 'settings' => array(...)));
  $variables['my_field_formatter2'] = $node->field_foo->view(array('type' => 'some_formatter', 'settings' => array(...)));
}
```

and then print my_field_formatter1 and my_field_formatter2 in your twig template for the node.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Don't know why but the preprocessor only works in a module not in a theme.

Comment: Glad to hear. Hmm... weird I think it should also be working in a theme. Not sure

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that™️: Use [Display Field Copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/display_field_copy)

From the module page:

> Display Field Copy provides the ability to make a display copy of a
>   field with Display Suite. The copy of the field can use a different
>   formatter (with different config) than the single field that is
>   currently available in core.
>
> For instance, if a site has a single entity reference field and the
>   display needs the list rendered on the page twice (once as a rendered
>   entity and once as a list of links). This module could be used to
>   create a copy of the field and apply a different formatter to it.
>
> This module does not have a copy limit. Theoretically, an unlimited
>   number of copies could be created. It should work for any field that
>   has at least one formatter available.